# Multiple user defined Variables in one MySQL statement ( SET ) possible?

Tags: mysql, variables, set

according to following SQL-Example:

```
SET @VARIABLE1 := (SELECT `row1` FROM `table` WHERE `xyz`= ...)
```

is it possible to define more than one variable with just one `SQL-Select`? I would like to `SET` two variables with one select-statement, e.g. row1, row2. Is this possible with `MySQL`?
Or shall I run two `SELECT`-Statements one after another like this:

```
SET @VARIABLE1 := (SELECT `row1`....)
SET @VARIABLE2 := (SELECT `row2`....)
```

Comment: **just one SQL-Select?** so try: `SET @VARIABLE2 := @VARIABLE1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set multiple variables in one select but you'll probably have to use a CASE statement to tell it when to set your variable if you're grabbing data from different rows.[sqlfiddle example of multiple variables from different rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fedbd/2/0)
unless you're grabbing data from different columns of the same row then you don't need a CASE statement 
[sqlfiddle example of multiple variables from same row](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fedbd/3/0)

Comment: Thank you, that has helped me. I've changed my Select Statement in SELECT @VAR1 := `row1`, @VAR2:=`row2`FROM `table` WHERE `xyz`= ... LIMIT 1